# Formatting new Date() into relative time that auto-updates regularly in angular-meteor

Tags: date, momentjs, date-formatting

I have a variable like this

```
var time = new Date();
```

How do I format it in angular-meteor into a relative time like one that shows up in facebook , twitter and other social apps like this  "3 hrs ago", "1 month ago" and so on .

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) **[`fromNow()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)** function, which will display the relative time.

For example:

```js
var time = new Date();
$('#timeFromNow').append(moment(time).fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

<div id="timeFromNow">Time from now: </div>
```

Please note that there is an official [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) Meteor package on [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment). If you want to install it, just run the following command:

```
meteor add momentjs:moment
```